# STR_TO_DATE and ISO8601 Atomtime format

Tags: mysql, datetime, atom-feed, timestamp-with-timezone, str-to-date

I have a MySQL database, which I cannot alter, where I read date from. The issue is that I have a varchar column that stores a date. The date is stored in the atomtime format eg. `2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00`.

I cannot figure how to specify the format in the STR_TO_DATE function. I tried `STR_TO_DATE(Endtime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+02:00')`, but that doesn't work.

Do anyone have a solution for this?

I am trying to run the following query (which is not working properly):

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as antal 
 FROM ivocall_calls
WHERE Agentname LIKE 'Vinh Nguyen'
  AND Status1 = 'SALG'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(Endtime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+02:00') 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+02:00') 
            AND STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-30T00:00:00+02:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+02:00')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably best-addressed using a stored function to parse and convert the timestamps from the stored format into MySQL's native format, using the built-in date time math functions to do the time zone conversions.

The function below will correctly handle two formats, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` and `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+/-HH:MM` as well as correctly formed MySQL datetime literals, which will be passed through unmodified.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `from_iso8601_subset` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `from_iso8601_subset`(in_ts TINYTEXT) RETURNS DATETIME
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN

-- this function takes an input timestamp value in a suppported subset of iso8601 values, and
-- and converts it to the equivalent MySQL datetime value, expressed in the current session's
-- time zone.  Since this is also the timezone that columns in the TIMESTAMP data type expect,
-- this causes the input value to be stored correctly in the native TIMESTAMP format, which is.
-- UTC under the hood.

-- if you are taking the value here and stuffing it into a DATETIME column, you need to have your
-- session @@time_zone set to the same zone in which that column should be stored, or use
-- CONVERT(from_iso('input value'),'UTC','Your Desired Time Zone');

-- 2014-02-01T23:59:59Z --

IF (in_ts REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[T ][[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}(Z|[+-][[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})$') THEN

  SET in_ts = REPLACE(REPLACE(in_ts, 'T', ' '), 'Z', '+00:00');
  RETURN CONVERT_TZ(SUBSTRING(in_ts FROM 1 FOR 19), SUBSTRING(in_ts FROM 20 FOR 24), @@time_zone);

-- unexpected format -- let MySQL's built-in functions do the best they can; this will throw warnings
-- if the input is not a yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss datetime literal; alternately this could return NULL.

ELSE

  RETURN CAST(in_ts AS DATETIME);

END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example output:

```
mysql> SET @@time_zone = 'America/New_York';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT from_iso8601_subset('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| from_iso8601_subset('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-05-31 18:00:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> set @@time_zone = 'UTC';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT from_iso8601_subset('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| from_iso8601_subset('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-05-31 22:00:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

We assume that if the input data matches one of the patterns, then the contents of the value passed in are also going to be sane; if you give nonsense input values, you'll get some nonsense output, such as if you are using a time zone of '+99:00' but it won't fail.  This function does not have any SQL injection vulnerabilities.

The code could be further-optimized, but as written, this function is efficient enough that it can evaluate several thousand expressions per second on a moderately-powered machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use unix_timestamp() instead:

```
SELECT something, COUNT() as antal FROM ivocall_calls 
WHERE Agentname LIKE 'Vinh Nguyen' 
AND Status1 = 'SALG' 
AND unix_timestamp(Endtime) BETWEEN 
    unix_timestamp('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00' and unix_timestamp('2014-06-30T00:00:00+02:00');
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! 

You are missing a bracket in your query, this query works:
`SELECT *, COUNT(*) as antal FROM ivocall_calls WHERE Agentname LIKE 'Vinh Nguyen' AND Status1 = 'SALG' AND unix_timestamp(Endtime) BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2014-06-01T00:00:00+02:00') AND unix_timestamp('2014-06-30T00:00:00+02:00')`

Comment: Interesting answer, but very wrong.  The unix_timestamp function, at best, is ignoring the time zone information in its argument, and assuming the session's time zone. Run that query, and then `SHOW WARNINGS;`.

Comment: @Michael: I'm always happy to learn something new. Maybe my solution still is applicable for the OP, if all their entries are in the same time zone. But I have to concede that then it's not a recommendable solution.

Comment: Interesting point @Michael-sqlbot. In this particular situation the timezone is the same for all entries. Any clues about a proper solution?

Comment: If you use day dates only and not the exact time, then you can use also the date() function instead of the unix_timestamp() function. But it seems to have the same flaw of not honouring the time zone.

Comment: @AlexMonthy thanks for the concession; humorously enough, if all the times are in the same format and time zone, a *lexical* comparison without any datetime hackery would be the simplest approach, given a design that can't be changed... in the sense that 'boy' `BETWEEN` 'apple' `AND`  'dog' correctly evaluates to `TRUE` and if the column is indexed, the index remains usable.

Comment: @Michael, you are right, of course. And who knows, my naive approach might even work for denn. We're still lacking a viable solution, though - wanna give it a try?

Comment: My concern with your approach is that it will give the appearance of working, but may have hidden edge cases.  I do have a solution in the form of a user defined function, but I've forgotten which codebase it's hiding in.  Still looking for it.