# Is there a way to extract the timezone as number from timestamp?

Tags: mysql, timezone, extract

I have a JSON column in MySQL 5.7 with object containing different timezones and I need to select everything adjusted to single timezone.
I use

```
DATE_FORMAT(sb.CONTENT ->> "$.field5", "%m/%d/%Y") AS START_DATE
```

and this formats the date, but I need it adjusted for certain timezone

Tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2019-07-02T00:10:00.000Z', '+00:00', '-7:00')
```

seems like a function for this, but it requires the initial timezone as parameter. Is there a proper way to extract just the timezone, or a function that would use he one from the timestamp ?

Comment: I don't think MySQL stores timezones in `datetime` values. If your times are in different timezones, you need to store the timezone in a column of your own.

Comment: @Barmar, good point. Wrong wording. The column is actually JSON and I use 
DATE_FORMAT(sb.CONTENT ->> "$.field5", "%m/%d/%Y") AS `START_DATE`
And I need to adjust the timezone

Comment: You still need to store the timezone explicitly in your table.

Comment: it is in the string. Like this one: '2019-07-02T00:10:00.000Z' or in other records it looks like this "'2019-07-01T00:10:00-0700'. The information is there. I have no access to the code, so I need to use MySQL means to deal with this.

Comment: There's no built-in method to extract the timezone from a string like that. You can use `SUBSTR()`, but you'll need to handle the `Z` case specially.

Comment: Why don't you use a consistent format for your times?

Comment: @ILS take a look at this example stored function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312077/1695906  I don't think it handles timestamps with fractional seconds, but may give you a place to start.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't have access to the entire code. This it what I have to work with. I totally agree with you though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Michael-sqlbot! This looks good and I can live without the fractions of seconds.